# T-SQL Create UID based on Columns and Iterate over it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following code which evaluates different time periods and takes the difference between them, for each group,

For example

```
TimePeriod  Value1
201607      50
201608      80
```

The code subtracts 80-50 = 30 (Periodic).

I also have a UID created based on several columns in my table. I have to use this custom UID and can't use the PK on the table, or any particular column.

```
WITH cte
AS (SELECT

  ISNULL(CAST(TransactionID AS nvarchar), '_nullTransactionId_') + ISNULL(Description, '_nullDescription_') + CAST(Account AS nvarchar) + Category + Currency + Entity + Scenario AS UID,

  LEFT(TimePeriod, 6) Period,
  SUM(Value1) Value1,
  CAST(LEFT(TimePeriod, 6) + '01' AS date) ord_date
FROM MyTestTable
GROUP BY LEFT(TimePeriod, 6),
         TransactionID,
         Description,
         Account,
         Category,
         Currency,
         Entity,
         Scenario,
         TimePeriod)
SELECT
  a.UID,
  a.Period,
  --a.Value1,
  ISNULL(a.Value1, 0) - ISNULL(b.Value1, 0) Periodic
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b
  ON a.ord_date = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, b.ord_date)
ORDER BY a.UID
```

The issue is that this code generates many more results than I have rows in my table. When I looked at it closely, I can see that the first (Periodic) result of any given UID is correct, but the subsequent ones wrong.

I'm not sure where to start to move towards a solution, I'm thinking the GROUP BY may be causing this, but I 'have' to list the fields in group by, otherwise I cannot make the UID.

Any guidance very much appreciated.

Comment: For us to be able to help much we need more details. Here is a great place to start for improving your question. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ I also notice you are converting to nvarchar but you don't specify the length. You should always specify the length. Did you know that the default length changes based on how it is used? I also have a feeling your ord_date is a varchar column instead of a datetime. You really should store datetime information in a datetime datatype.

Comment: @SeanLange - thanks for providing the URL with that. Sometimes asking is the hard part, I'm going to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the evaluation made for each UID right? In this case you are missing the UID in the join clause.

The query should be:

```
WITH cte
AS (SELECT

  ISNULL(CAST(TransactionID AS nvarchar), '_nullTransactionId_') + ISNULL(Description, '_nullDescription_') + CAST(Account AS nvarchar) + Category + Currency + Entity + Scenario AS UID,

  LEFT(TimePeriod, 6) Period,
  SUM(Value1) Value1,
  CAST(LEFT(TimePeriod, 6) + '01' AS date) ord_date
FROM MyTestTable
GROUP BY LEFT(TimePeriod, 6),
         TransactionID,
         Description,
         Account,
         Category,
         Currency,
         Entity,
         Scenario,
         TimePeriod)
SELECT
  a.UID,
  a.Period,
  --a.Value1,
  ISNULL(a.Value1, 0) - ISNULL(b.Value1, 0) Periodic
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b
  ON a.UID = b.UID and a.ord_date = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, b.ord_date)
ORDER BY a.UID
```

Comment: Awesome spotter! Thanks